# Combine PowerPoint documents

Tags: document-set, powerpoint, powerpoint-services

We are trying to combine 10-20 PowerPoint documents into a single document (PPT and then PDF) on a regular basis.

What are possible solutions for this in SharePoint (2013)?

I started looking into Document Sets but haven't understood yet if they allow such a use case.

Comment: Document sets are basically "folders" to logically group related documents. If you really want to merge those files into one, there is afaik no out of the box solution. But you can use for example AdLib. Or create your own web services using OpenXML SDK and call it from SP 2013 workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you can do this OOTB, you have to write your own code or use the 3rd part tool.

- EnvoaPoint has [Automate Document Management](http://www.enovapoint.com/jungledoc/tour/), they have trial version too.
- You can use Open XML, Open XML SDK 2, Microsoft Office Interop, Microsoft Office Object Library and Visual Studio 2013. [Merge PowerPoint Presentations (PPTX) & save as PDF](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/710055/Merge-PowerPoint-Presentations-PPTX-save-as-PDF)

Comment: Thank you for the nice link. I'll give it a couple of days to see if anybody has a OOTB solution